# install grequests but error: "No module named grequests"

Tags: python, grequests

https://i.stack.imgur.com/QUGyz.png

It says grequests is succesfull installed. But when i want to import it. I get a error saying "No module named grequests"

How can i fix this?

System = OS 10.11.6

Answer (score 0):

In command line

pip list

Check package in there

Comment: What version python you use? I m asking that if you install for python2 it supposed to be like pip install grequest, if it is for python3 it supposed to be like pip3 install grequest. That might be reason

Comment: i use python version 2. When i do import grequests in my terminal it doesnt give a error. Only when i import it into jupyter notebook.

Comment: i use python version 2,7,10. When i do import grequests in my terminal it doesnt give a error. Only when i import it into jupyter notebook. I think it might be that grequests is downloaded for another version?

Comment: Same python  version on jupyter ?

Comment: Upgrade version using  pip install  -U grequest

Comment: i run 2.7.12 in jupyter notebook

Comment: This is for upgrades packages  or you can install specific version using this : pip install grequest==1.0.1

Comment: I don't know grequest version, just I guessed